# Disassembling Simple Hello World program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, assembly, compiler-construction

I wrote this small C++ program and built it(Release)

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
     std::cout<<"Hello World";
     return 0;
}
```

When I disassemble it, it has a lot of extra code(security cookie etc..). I believe Visual Studio is adding all those. How can I compile this program without any extra information, so that its easy to understand its disassembled code?

I know assembly is comparatively harder, but what I mean is getting a hello world asm code out of a hello world c++ program. Is this possible?

Comment: `operator<<` on `std::cout` will require a lot of inane machine code. You don't want to do that manually.

Comment: @zneak- How about recompiling in C, with printf?

Comment: printf could be a way to go. Still, i/o in general is tedious using assembly. I'd start with functions that calculate simple things and use them from C code.

Comment: @zneak- Something like simple addition?

Comment: that would probably be a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting with a huge code base with `<iostream>`. What you might want to do is avoid the use of a runtime library entirely. Try something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteFile(stdout, "Hello world\n", 12, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile that with assembly listing turned on, and that should give you some "raw" Win32 code to start with.

Comment: windows.h won't add any extra code? and there are three options for Assembly listing, which one to choose?

Comment: All Windows programs link with (at least) `kernel32.dll`, so no, including `<windows.h>` won't add anything extra. The compiler will still add its own startup code, though.

Comment: @GregHewgill- And which option to choose for Assembler Output? Also kernel32.dll == windows.h? (Off-topic)

Comment: I'm not sure which options you're looking at. What are they? The `<windows.h>` header covers functions exported from many of the Win32 DLLs, including `kernel32.dll` and many others.

Comment: Project Propeties-> Configuration-> C/C++-> Output Files->Assembler Output.. and that has 1.No listing(Default)  2.Assembly- Listing Only  3.Assembly With Machine Code  4.Assembly with Source Code   5.Assembly with Machine Code and Source code

Comment: That just controls how much detail you get. Option (4), Assembly with Source Code, is probably the most useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can generate assembly output  in Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Output Files -> Assembler Output

This will let you see the assembly for the code you wrote.

Diassembling, you are going to get a bunch of other things that are linked in.

Comment: I want to learn disassembling.. thats why following that path(Compiling and disassembling). Also which option to choose under Assembler output.. there are three?

Comment: Disassembling is a mechanical task. Reading and understanding the assembly code, that's the tricky bit. For that, you might as well start with compiler-generated code. Also, C code generates more straightforward assembly code than C++. Also, books are your friends - assembly language is not something you can just pick up by staring at it. Read up first.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev- Sir, I have already read some basics of Assembly, and was feeling like looking at some real disassembled code.

Comment: what are you using for disassmbly?

Answer (score 0):

To control visual studio code generation features, rigth click on your project in VS -> properties -> Configuration properties -> c/c++ -> code generation.

Don't forget to select the right build configuration (debug, release, etc...).

The security cookies can be removed by playing with the buffer security check (/GS by default)